# How to Perform GroupBy , Having and Order by together in Pyspark

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I am looking for a solution where i am performing GROUP BY, HAVING CLAUSE and ORDER BY Together in a Pyspark Code. Basically we need to shift some data from one dataframe to another with some conditions.

The SQL Query looks like this which i am trying to change into Pyspark

```
SELECT TABLE1.NAME, Count(TABLE1.NAME) AS COUNTOFNAME, 
Count(TABLE1.ATTENDANCE) AS COUNTOFATTENDANCE INTO SCHOOL_DATA_TABLE
FROM TABLE1
WHERE (((TABLE1.NAME) Is Not Null))
GROUP BY TABLE1.NAME
HAVING (((Count(TABLE1.NAME))>1) AND ((Count(TABLE1.ATTENDANCE))<>5))
ORDER BY Count(TABLE1.NAME) DESC;
```

The Spark Code which i have tried and failing is:
What i have done the i have taken columns from df to df2 on which operations need to be done:

```
df2= df.select('NAME','ATTENDANCE')
    df2=df2.groupBy('NAME').agg(count('NAME').alias('name1').agg(count('ATTENDANCE').alias('NEW_ATTENDANCE'))).filter((col('name1')>1) & (col('NEW_ATTENDANCE') !=5))
```

SAMPLE DATA

```
rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize([
    ('Aayush', 10),
    ('Aayush', 9),
    ('Shiva', 5 ),
    ('Alia', 6),
    ('Aayan', 11),
    ('Alia',9)])
df_1 = spark.createDataFrame(rdd, schema=['NAME','ATTENDANCE'])
```

Comment: `agg` can take multiple aggregations. Try passing 2 counts like this `agg(count().alias(), count().alias())`

Comment: Based on answer provided by @Emma, ```df2= df_1.select('NAME','ATTENDANCE')
df2 = df2.groupBy('NAME').agg(count('NAME').alias('name1'),count('ATTENDANCE').alias('NEW_ATTENDANCE')).filter("name1 > 1 and NEW_ATTENDANCE !=5")
df2.show(10,True)```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is almost ok, after fixing a few syntax issues it works.
Also, I think for "attendance" you want to use `sum` rather than `count` (otherwise it will be always the same value as of name count).
For sorting, simply add `orderBy`.

```
df.withColumn("NAME", lower("NAME"))
.groupBy('NAME')
.agg(count('NAME').alias('name1'),sum('ATTENDANCE').alias('NEW_ATTENDANCE'))
.filter((col('name1')>1) & (col('NEW_ATTENDANCE') !=5))
.orderBy(col("NAME"))
```

Comment: hi @Grisha Thanks for your answer , but there is ine issue i am facing actually there are two values in NAME Column having name as 'Virat' and 'virat', due to lower case in second case it is not taking that value in group by

Comment: I want to pick that virat after group by whose conditions are satisfying with filter conditions

Comment: if you want to treat the names case insensitive, simply convert them to lower case before the group by - `df = df.withColumn("NAME", lower("NAME"))`

Comment: But Isn't there any way other than lowering whole column values

Comment: Maybe I don't understand what you need, with the example above "Virat" and "virat" , do you want to have both these entries in the result or you want them to be merged ? or anything else?

Comment: If you want them to be merged, the standard way is to use "lower", if you want to keep them separately you don't need to do anything as they will be grouped separately...

Comment: hi @Grisha My query here is if we have both values as Virat and virat in column names then after group by it should pick both the values but we want only that value  whose count1>1 and attendance !=5

Comment: so basically after doing GROUP BY It must pick both values right (Virat, virat) as both have same name and out of those two values we will pick that values which is matching with our filter conditions

Comment: as i don't want to change every value in column NAME to lowrcase

Comment: In your final result, for (Virat, virat) are you expecting to have two rows or one? If you are going to have one, which one? Again, if you logically treat those names as the same name you are supposed to normalize them in advance (for example via "lower"). Also note that `lower` doesn't add any performance overhead because it's performed during the read of data anyway.

Comment: yes i have changed the column to lower case and take it in separate df, it is working thanks for the suggestion